# Exsecuting SuiteCRM call synchronously using NodeJs

Tags: node.js, sugarcrm, suitecrm

I am updating data in SuiteCRM using set entry call. But my issue is that the call is asynchronous and what I want it to be synchronous. My code in node js. Kindly help me out.

```
CRM.set_entry("Cases",array_to_set_entry[i],function(err1, res1, body1){
console.log("I am inside crm set_entry");
    if (body1 && typeof body1.id !== constant.undefined) {

        console.log("checkCRM")
    }
else {
    console.log("checkCRM failed")
    } });
```

I searched stack overflow for solutions. I found async.queue() as a possible solution but still i am not getting how to use it in my case.